# Azure Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'null'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote an app and I am trying upload it on Azure. The app runs ok locally and has a SQL Server database as the backend; the app is based off MVC.

When I try to access a page such as /person, I get this error:

```
Azure Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'null'.
```

Anyone ever dealt with such an error and how did you resolve it.

I have tried a few suggestions but none seems to work:

- adding  to config file
- setting Persist Security Info=False to true

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the app's data connection, the connection string had no userid. Adding a userid fixed the issue. Even though when the app was published with a proper connection string, the user id was empty.

Comment: Thanks for posting! I had the same problem. I didn't realize that azure managed connection strings. I thought whatever I pushed out in my web.config got used.

Comment: Where is this dataconnection string? I have the proper connection string in the web.config file as well as in the azure portal.

Comment: I've been using Azure web apps and azure sql databases for years and this is the first time I have experiences this user null issue.  I have not prepared my publish or even publish to azure differently than before.