# asp net core deployment results in error: SqlException: Login failed for user 'null'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I'm deploying an ASP .NET Core web application that uses a SQL Server database to Microsoft Azure. I've created an "app service" with a SQL Server instance on Azure. When I deploy the application from Visual Studio to Azure, the deployment ends up opening a browser window with the message

> "An error occurred while starting the application". In the application log I find the error "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'null'."

The connect string used to configure the deployment is the one I copied from the Azure management console. If I use the same connection string with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio running on my notebook, I successfuly  connect to the database. When run locally, using the local database, the application runs fine.

These are the files deployed on the Azure (in the code "my_" is replacing sensitive data):

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=my_database;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
    "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "System": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Information"
        }
    }
}
```

appsettings.Production.json

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings":  {
      "DefaultConnection":  "Server=tcp:my_server.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=my_db;Persist Security Info=False;User Id=my_user_id;Password=my_password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you verify the connection string which is actually used by the application deployed on Azure?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39731704/azure-exception-details-system-data-sqlclient-sqlexception-login-failed-for-us this might help you

Comment: Were the connection string not good, I wouldn't be able to connect to the DB using SQL Server Management Studio. On the linked page I don't understand what is the solution? Where should the Userid be added? I tried to go to the Azure app setting page, deleted the published connection string and added one manually, but is still doesn't work...

Comment: My comment was around to check if the settings are being published correctly.

Comment: If published means appsettings.json on the Azure, then yes, as you can see in the code above.

Comment: If it is using connection string mentioned in appsettings.json then there is no username in that connection string. That means that' the faulty connection string. If it uses appsettings.Production.json then it should work fine. If still not working fine then its a issue. That's when it's needed to verify which connection string is being used...

Comment: It's using the right connection string - I know it beacause in the log i see the following message: Opening connection to database 'xxxxx' on server 'tcp:yyyyy.database.windows.net,1433'

Comment: The link the @ChetanRanpariya provided suggests that the connection string can get mangled when deploying to Azure. You need to somehow verify what the config file looks like in Azure after deployment.

Comment: Yes I did, I connected to Azure cloud with Visual Studio, opened the Web service node and checked the file contents.

Comment: If you get `startup` errors you can enable extra startup options to output the actual reason. Have a look at my blog post about it. http://pkula.blogspot.co.uk/2017/11/asp-net-core-how-to-fix-error-occurred.html

Answer (score 0):

Azure it super particular about its connection string. Mostly around the User ID field. 
Below is a template version of my connection string that I use to connect to an Azure DB.

```
"Server=tcp:MyDatabaseServer.database.windows.net;Database=MyDatabaseName;User ID= MyDatabaseName@MyDatabaseServer.database.windows.net; Password=MyPassword;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

What i found is that I was getting errors when I didn't include the @MyDatabaseServer.database.windows.net

Maybe try subbing your information into this and seeing what happens. I am sure you already know how to get the DB servers host name and the local username for the DB. If you don't let me know and I can do some screen shots.